# Don't allow null value to update column if already contains data

Tags: sql

I have a source that I am pulling data from to update an existing table.

Is a way to update the values in each field only if the source data is not `NULL`?

Comment: I don't understand how you are doing an insert and having troubles with updating values (aren't you inserting not updating?).  Want to give more information on whats going on here?

Comment: maybe `UPDATE table SET column = CASE WHEN @input IS NULL THEN column ELSE @input END`?

Comment: Sorry yes, I am doing an update if it meets certain criteria. Just dont want to update a column that has data with a null.

Comment: @user2395035 - Can you please clarify if you want the _entire_ row updated if a single field is not `NULL` -or- you want any field updated as long was the _field_ is not `NULL`, in which case some values will be updated but not otheres.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ISNULL(@paramA, ColumnA)`:

```
UPDATE someTable
set ColumnA = ISNULL(@ParamA, ColumnA)
WHERE
.....
```

Comment: I would like to leave the current data in the column if the updating value is NULL.

Comment: This answer achieves this objective.

Answer (score -1):

take into consideration that u mentioned if source data is not null then update

```
--Create a sample table

DECLARE @SAMPLE TABLE
(
SourceID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
SourceData NVARCHAR(255)
)

--Create dummy data

INSERT INTO @SAMPLE VALUES ('SOMETHING')
INSERT INTO @SAMPLE VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO @SAMPLE VALUES ('SOMETHING')


--update source data that is not null, this will update entire table

UPDATE @SAMPLE
SET SourceData = 'New Data'
FROM @SAMPLE t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT * FROM @SAMPLE Where SourceData is not null) t2 
ON t1.SourceID = t2.SourceID
```

OR if you just want to update selected records

```
--Pass in your variable

DECLARE @SourceID INT

--play around your source id

SET @SourceID = 2

--if the particular id is with null data, then update will never perform

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @SAMPLE WHERE SourceID = @SourceID and SourceData is not null)
Update @SAMPLE
set SourceData = 'New Item'
where SourceID = @SourceID
```

Comment: Your solutions do not work in the way the OP is asking. They want to update _all_ rows matching the Source table but when a _field_ in the source data is `NULL` ignore it and leave the existing field data. Your answer only updates the _entire_ row if one field is `NOT NULL`.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, so there are 2 table source table and target table, whenever, OP want to update target table based on source table data whenever source data is not null?